# How to make VSCode automatically insert 'end' on enter press after 'do'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

I wanted to try out visual studio code for writing ruby/rails and came across this issue that when I write 'do' in the editor and then hit enter then 'end' is not automatically added to the next line.

Writing 'def' + enter works fine. 'begin' + enter works fine too, but not 'do' + enter.

I haven't found any extension that would make it work yet and google has not been much help either. Maybe there's a way to define the snipper myself?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Any reason for using visual studio for this? RubyMine is built specifically for ruby and has a lot of nice code exploration and completion at a very affordable cost.

Comment: Just to test it out as a free alternative to sublime text 3.

Comment: Atom (https://atom.io/) will autocomplete `do`...`enter`.

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but I asked specifically if vscode could do that too somehow.

Comment: This vscode extension seems to do the trick: https://github.com/kaiwood/vscode-endwise

Comment: Voting to reopen, as this is a completely legitimate question for stackoverflow with clear explanation of the problem, and requirement for a solution.

Comment: To expand on @TylerAmos comment, in vscode, go to Extensions -> search 'endwise' -> install it. (you don't have to restart vscode or anything, try it out, you'll get the closing 'end'!). That should be the accepted answer once the question is reopened.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a workaround that suffices for now.
Using Code -> Preferences -> User Snippers -> Ruby I added the following snippets

```
"Do block": {
    "prefix": "dob",
    "body": [
        "do",
        "\t$0",
        "end"
    ],
    "description": "Do block"
},
"Do block with params": {
    "prefix": "dobwp",
    "body": [
        "do |${1:param}|",
        "\t$0",
        "end"
    ],
    "description": "Do block with params"
}
```

The first one inserts a

```
do

end
```

without any parameters.
The second one inserts a

```
do |param|

end
```

and you can choose the param value.

The downside is that when writing do you have to move down and choose dob or dobwp and it's not the default behaviour of do like in sublime.

Answer (score 6):

This extension will do exactly what you wished for:

`vscode-endwise`: This is an extension that wisely adds the "end" keyword to code structures in languages like Ruby or Crystal while keeping the correct indentation levels

- https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=kaiwood.endwise

Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

Did you try https://github.com/rubyide/vscode-ruby ?
It states that

> This extension provides rich Ruby language and debugging support for
>   VS Code.

including Autocomplete. Maybe worth a try.

Comment: Yes, I have it installed. It does not include it unfortunately.

Comment: It's disabled by default. Code > Preferences > Settings > Extensions > Ruby: Code Completion. Works well with methods, classes, and modules.

Comment: @rtrojanowski near as I can tell that Code Completion setting does not work with blocks as the op requested